# How to use transactions with C# and Sybase

Tags: c#, transactions, odbc, sybase

I have done plenty of transaction processing in .net using both VB and C# when accessing SQL server.  But I can not get the transaction process to work when using odbc with Sybase.

I found somewhere where I need to "SET CHAINED OFF", I have done that, but no matter what after calling my insert procedure from C# it has already done the commit.

I want to in my C# execute a insert PROC, come back to my code, do some other processing and then either commit or rollback.

Does anyone have an example of making multiple calls to Sybase within one transaction, and then rolling back or committing?

Here is an example ...

```
        sbConnection = new OdbcConnection(StrConnectionString);
        sbCommand = new OdbcCommand();

        sbCommand.Connection = sbConnection;
        sbConnection.Open();
        sbTransaction = sbConnection.BeginTransaction();


        sbCommand.Connection = sbConnection;
        sbCommand.Transaction = sbTransaction; ;

        sbCommand.CommandText = "SET CHAINED OFF";
        sbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //sbCommand.Transaction = sbTransaction;
        sbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sbCommand.CommandText = "{call myInsertProc (?, ?, ?, ?)}";
        sbCommand.Parameters.Clear();

        sbCommand.Parameters.Add("@col1", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = field1;
        sbCommand.Parameters.Add("@col2", OdbcType.BigInt, 14).Value = Convert.ToInt64(field2);
        sbCommand.Parameters.Add("@col3", OdbcType.BigInt, 14).Value = Convert.ToInt64(field3);
        sbCommand.Parameters.Add("@col4", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = textData;

        sbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // these two statements are for testing only.  The rollback is not working, its still getting committed.
        sbTransaction.Rollback();
        sbConnection.Close();
```

Comment: I found a work-a-round.  But this cant be the correct way.  I put a "Begin Transaction" in my stored procedure with no "commit" or "rollback".  I was able to execute my stored procedure from my .net code, then comeback and do either a rollback, or commit using the same connection.    There has to be a better way, does anyone know how?